my proof on uniqueness of Haar measure
I want to prove that the Haar measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space is unique up to multiplication by a constant. Here is my argument:
Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two Haar measures on a locally compact Hausdorff (LCH) space (X). Let
$$ I_1(f) = \int_{X} f \, d\mu $$
$$ I_2(f) = \int_{X} f \, d\nu $$
for any $f \in C_c(X)$. Now, due to the Riesz representation theorem, we have:
$$ I_1(f) = \int_{X} f g_1 \, d\nu $$
$$ I_2(f) = \int_{X} f g_2 \, d\mu $$
for some $g_1, g_2 \in C_c(X)$. It is easy to check that these two functions need to be positive.
Considering:
$$ I_1(f) I_2(f) = \left( \int_{X} f g_1 \, d\mu \right) \left( \int_{X} f \, d\mu \right) = I_1(f^2) I_1(g_1) $$
where the change of integration is due to Fubini's theorem. The same argument shows:
$$ I_1(f) I_2(f) = I_2(f^2) I_2(g_2) $$
Changing $f$ to $\sqrt{f}$ yields:
$$ \frac{I_1(f)}{I_2(f)} = \frac{I_2(g_2)}{I_1(g_1)} > 0 $$
But I'm not sure where I am using the fact that these two are Haar measures, so my suspicion is that the proof is wrong somehow.
Thanks for your help!

Integrals don't distribute over products in general, hence the use of the product rule on the reals for instance.

Ahaaa I need to assume support of two set can be shifted in a way the do not intersect

In addition to the other comments, there is no such thing as a Haar measure on an LCH space. There are Haar measures on LCH groups, and you will not be able to show uniqueness without using the group structure and the translation invariance of Haar measures.

Take $$X=\mathbb{Z}_p$$ the $p$-adic integers equipped with its Haar measure and normalize so that $X$ measures $1$. Let $f$ be the indicator function $1_{p\mathbb{Z}_p}$ and $g$ be 1. Then $$I(f)I(fg)= 1/p^2$$ but $$I(f^2)I(g)=1/p$$

Ahaaa thanks.
isn't there anyway to make the conclusion via this idea?

I don't know of one.

Thanks for your help.
Btw it seems correct for me that my argument works under the further assumption that any two compact subsets can be shifted s.t the do not intersect(this is possible for example in $R^d$).
what is your idea?
